# How to match element by jquery dynamic generated id and value

Tags: jquery

Please excuse if this is a dumb question

I have the following HTML

```
<div data-role="panel" id="rightpanelforstartpage" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="b">
            <div class="ui-panel-inner">
                <div class="tpMenuWrap">
                    <a href="#demo-links" data-rel="close" class="icon-cancel-circled-1 panelCloseBtn"></a>
                    <ul class="ul_menu">
                        <li><a>My Recent Orders</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="recentOrderslistWrap">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btMenuWrap">
                    <ul class="ul_menu">
                        <li><a>About OMS</a></li>
                        <li><a>FAQs</a></li>
                        <li><a>Send Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For which i need to match with the id and class

I know the following will work

```
$("#rightpanelforstartpage .recentOrderslistWrap")
```

But in case the id is dynamic then how to achive the above ??

I have tried the below

```
var valofpageid = 'rightpanelforstartpage' ;

$('#'+valofpageid+ .recentOrderslistWrap).html("");
```

With this i am getting

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .**

Could you please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: What exactly do you expect `foo + .recentOrderslistWrap` to do?  `.recentOrderslistWrap` is invalid JavaScript. The only places where `.` is acceptable is in number literals (`4.5`) or property access (`foo.bar`). I wonder why you put `#` inside a string literal but didn't think to do the same with `.recentOrderslistWrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially concatenating **strings** so you need to *continue* the string concatenation like

```
$('#'+valofpageid+' .recentOrderslistWrap').html("");
```

Answer (score 2):

The error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .** is caused by this line:

```
$('#'+valofpageid+ .recentOrderslistWrap).html("");
```

You are attempting string concatenation without quoting the text.

Change it to this:

```
$('#'+valofpageid+ '.recentOrderslistWrap').html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use as below :

`$('#'+valofpageid+ '.recentOrderslistWrap').html("");`

Comment: you're missing a space before the dot